# Does an attractive force from a positive charge outside a hydrogen atom change the shape of the 1s orbital?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, charge

[image: External attraction]

For a polarized atom, hydrogen for simplicity, being acted upon by some positive "rod" pulling on the valence electron. The illustration above shows the s orbital being stretched into an oval pointed toward the positive rod. My intuition is telling me that this is actually not the case. But rather an illustrative metaphor for applying the position operator to the electron's wave function. So that when the wave function collapses it is more likely to be on the side of the orbital facing the rod. Thus, while the electron is in a state of uncertainty, a greater proportion of its probability density is on one side, creating polarization. Is this correct? Or does the shape of the orbital actually change?

Comment: Consider the H2 molecule...

Comment: Or, to be more specific, the H$^{+}_{2}$ ion.

Answer (score 1):

You can study the [Stark effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_effect) to answer your question. When one applies an external electric field, the Hamiltonian is changed and both the wave function and the energy spectrum are changed.

Answer (score 0):

> While the electron is in a state of uncertainty, a greater proportion of its probability density is on one side, creating polarization. Is this correct?

> Or does the shape of the orbital actually change?

The orbital is defined by the probability density. So yes, the probability density changes, effectively polarizing the atom. This is indistinguishable from saying that the shape of the orbit changes.